# Multiple UITableViewBugs with refreshControl

Tags: ios

I have build a very simple demo app to illustrate the two bugs that I found when using UIViewController with tableView installed. These issues are not present if I use a standard UITableviewController.

[Video to demonstrate the bug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TEF7ofN_kE&feature=youtu.be)

[project link to github](https://github.com/eddy80310/PullToRefreshBug)

1. Basically, when I pull to refresh slowly, I get this jump (approximately 30 points) downwards. I would also need to drag a fair bit down before the refresher is activated (half the screen approx). If I pull fast though, the issue is not there.
2. If I implement hideNavigationBarOnSwipe and refreshControl at the same time, the section header because all ugly and out of place (Shown later in the video).

I was wondering, for this sort of bug, if I want to take a shot to see if Apple improved it, which of the following three options should I give it a go. (This project is built on xcode7.3, swift 2, IOS9.0

1. Update from swift 2 to swift 3.
2. Update Xcode from 7 to 8
3. Build the app for a higher IOS version

----Full Code----

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.dataSource = self

        navigationController!.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true

        refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.refresh), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        myTableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    }

    func refresh() {

    }

    @IBAction func stopRefreshingBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "section \(indexPath.section) row \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "Section Header \(section)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTableView.delegate = self
    myTableView.dataSource = self
    navigationController!.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true

    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

    //Create an instance of a UITableViewController. This will host your UITableView.
     let tableController = UITableViewController()

    //Add tableController as a childViewController and set its tableView property to your UITableView.
    self.addChildViewController(tableController)
    tableController.tableView = myTableView
    tableController.refreshControl = self.refreshControl
}
```

Comment: Great solution. And thanks for pointing out that "UIRefreshControl's aren't meant to be subviews, they're meant to be the table's refresh control. 
It assume it as a cell, rather than just a subview, which forces a recalculate around it."